# Replace missing values with default one

Tags: javascript, object

Example:

```
this.themes.basic = {
  background: "black",
  specialThings: {
    border: "1px
  }

}

this.themeObj: {
  background: "black",
  specialThings: {}
}
```

I need a function that scans this.themeObj and replaces missing values 
with the value of this.themes.basic. It also should scan child's of the Object. PS: pls don't use eval if it is possible

Thanks

Comment: Object.assign should do the job ?.

Comment: _"PS: pls don't use eval if it is possible"_ - Sounds like a homework/assignment

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried? Stack Overflow isn't a free code writing service. It is expected you show your attempts to solve your own issue and other people help you fix your code when it doesn't work as expected

Comment: Probably helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically

Comment: @Andreas, hahah !. JS has evolved alot lately though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try with:

```
let themes = {
  background: "black",
  specialThings: {
    border: "1px"
  }
}

let themeObj = {
  background: "black",
  specialThings: {}
}

const object3 = {...themeObj, ...themes };
```